# Why can one expect that $n\cdot p$ elements complete the test?

Tags: probability

Suppose that the probability that an object complete a test is $p$ and there are $n$ objects.

Why may one then expect that $n\cdot p$ elements complete the test ?

I've tried modelling this by using the expectation of a random variable and the like, but haven't come to a conclusion on how to get this number of expected elements.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are after a non-rigorous but intuitive explanation ...

Imagine that you didn't know the probability p. You could work it out experimentally. You do your n trials a few hundred times, and find that on average the number of successful trials is some number s (s for success). From this you decide that the probability p = s/n. (Number of successful trials divided by the total number of trials).

Rearranging this formula gives you s = np. As s is the number of successful outcomes, this gives the formula you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have a sequence of [Bernoulli trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial), with the probability of success being $p$.

The [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $B(n,p)$ models the probability to have a certain number of successes in a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli trials, each with the probability of success being $p$.

If $X \sim B(n,p)$, then the expected value of $X$ is $np$.

More straightforward, let $X_k$ be the the random variable with $X_k = 1$ if object $k$ passes the test, 0 otherwise. Then $P(X_k = 1) = p$ and
$$E[X_k] = p \cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0 = p$$
through the linearity of expectation we get:
$$E[X_1 + \dots + X_n] = E[X_1] + \dots + E[X_n] = p + \dots + p = np.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with $n=1$. This single object by assumption completes the test with probability $p$. That is, the number of objects that completed the test is either $1$ (the single object completed the test, probability $p$) or $0$ (the single object didn't complete the test, probability $1-p$). By definition, the expectation value for $n=1$ is therefore:
$$\mathscr{E}(n=1) = p\cdot 1 + (1-p)\cdot 0 = p$$
So the expectation value of the number of objects completing the test in the case of one single object is just the probability of completing.

Now expectation values of independent events have the property that they add up (even if the events are not independent of each other). Since all your single tests by assumption have the same expectation value, $p$, your expectation value is
$$\mathcal{E}(n) = n\mathcal{E}(1) = np$$

Comment: I am not sure the $n$ tests being independent of each other is a crucial assumption, so long as they each have a probability $p$ of success.  Indeed if they are perfectly dependent and all fail or all succeed together then the expect number of successes is even more obviously $np$.

Comment: @Henry: You're right; I just cross-checked in Wikipedia, and the addition rule indeed does not require independence. I'll fix my answer accordingly, than you.